# How to call REST API using sessions in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm newly started xamarin forms.
I have already done with code using HttpClient but in my current application it depends on sessions means, once login has done based on sessions it will navigate to other screen. Without login hit other API

`https://***.com/Service/GetPage?`

I got the request response like below

```
https://****.com/?ReturnUrl=%2fService%2fGetPage
```

How can I resolve the issue.

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi - Would you be able to supply more info on what you are trying to do? Are you using a master page for navigation etc? In terms of passing data, best to use MVVM approach with viewmodel. Here is some good documentation on the Xamarin site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm

Comment: but how to maintain the sessions?

Comment: @NanduPsycho For sessions you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45276649/xamarin-forms-session-management

Comment: @NanduPsycho Are you trying to use same cookies come in response or something else ?